# Using jfrog x-ray to scan artifactory for vulnerable windows software

Tags: windows, security, jfrog-xray

Looking for examples of how X-Ray might help detect or prevent old versions of software being installed on Microsoft Windows machines.

We use hashicorp packer to build new windows images and sometimes a developer will sneak in an old dotnet or java installation.  If these came from our artifactory server can we use xray to inform us about anyone using these old versions?  I see examples of how linux machines are protected but not windows.

Comment: Try creating a generic repository and download the required packages and in Xray select block unscanned Artifacts option. This approach may help you, but not exactly sure!!!

Answer (score 0):

JFrog Xray does not support windows image (ISO) scanning today.

It can be a great feature for the roadmap.